# c# selenium date of birth

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

im currently creating a nike account generator script, and im struggling with something...

This is the html code of the Date of birth element: `<input id="b1dfefd8-5854-4140-84f9-6fccea1d6b93" type="date" placeholder="Date of Birth" value="" name="dateOfBirth" data-componentname="dateOfBirth" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" data-ddlabel="dd" data-mmlabel="mm" data-yyyylabel="yyyy" data-fillr-id="69698" data-fillr="bound">`

https://gyazo.com/1edaf83558e7d3a7c44f9c7220b17762
Here is a gif of the Button on Nike's website, so u can see how it acts.

i've tried to select it with xpath, id etc. and everything i have tried, has not worked yet, i want to change the value ofc, so i can choose from my code what to be in Date, and Month, and Year.

Thank you.

Comment: How about this? webdriver.executeScript("document.getElementById('b1dfefd8-5854-4140-84f9-6fccea1d6b93').setAttribute('value', '1988-01-01')");

Comment: Also, if you post what you currently have tried - code example - we can write up a suggested solution using the same variable names etc. and know exactly what you tried. thanks!

Comment: I have already told in the post, what i've tried, and your example doesnt work for me.

Comment: code trials please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the css selector and then set the value using the argument[0].

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Today;
(driver as IJavascriptExecutor).ExecuteScript("querySelector(\"input[name='dateOfBirth']\").setAttribute('value', 'arguments[0]')", date.ToString());
```

Comment: That doesnt work, also it isnt about the date, but date of birth.